# Keep getting undeclared variable error and I don't understand where from

Tags: java, compiler-errors, initialization

[My code](http://pastebin.com/0uAEGhR1)

I keep getting the error

```
main.java:77: error: variable fAnswer might not have been initialized
out.println("The answer is: " + fAnswer);
                                ^
```

and I can't find why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says that depending on the `choice` value, the `fAnswer` might not get initialized. If you have a `choice == 4` for example, `fAnswer` will not have a value assigned to it BEFORE you call `out.println("The answer is: " + fAnswer)`. This means that `fAnswer` will point to junk and it might not be what you want.

Try and define it at the point of declaration

```
double fAnswer = -1.0; // Or something like this.
```

Answer (score 0):

Well did you make sure it is always assigned a value before hitting this statement?

Update:  just read your code, so if the choice is 2 or 3, then the variable will never have been assigned.  But the compiler has no way of guaranteeing that the user will hit 2 or 3, so it warns you that this variable "may" not have been initialized.  Actually, anytime there's a conditional branch whose truth value depends on a variable or function return value, then the compiler will err on the safe side and decide that it can not guarantee which side of the branch it will take.  So for example:

```
boolean alwaysTrue = true;
int i;
if (alwaysTrue) {
    i = 1;
}
System.out.println("i is " + i);  // will generate error

if (true) {
    i = 1;
}
System.out.println("i is " + i);  // will not generate error
```

In conclusion, better to initialize to some known value.

Comment: Yes it gets assigned a value depending on the return value of one of the functions.

Comment: Please copy and paste the code segment here.  Please include when it is declared to when the println occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is not smart enough to know for sure that the variable has been assigned through all possible code paths before it is used on this particular line. To quiet the compiler, just give the variable a value when you declare it:

```
double fAnswer = 0.0;
```